# What makes this database's cascading deletes cyclical?

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-ce, relational-database, cascading-deletes

### Vendor


**(PK)** - Id
Name

### Stand


**(PK)** - Id
VendorId - *fk - cascaded delete if Vendor is deleted)*
Name

### Item


**(PK)** - Id
VendorId - *(fk - cascaded delete if Vendor is deleted)*
Name
Price

### UnavailableItem


**(PK)** - ItemId - *(fk - cascaded delete if Item is deleted)*
**(PK)** - StandId - *(fk - cascaded delete if Stand is deleted)*

#### The database above represents an athletic stadium.

Multiple Vendors exist (Bob's Pizza, Tom's Tacos...)

Multiple Stands exist for each Vendor (Bob's Pizza Concourse A, Bob's Pizza Concourse B...)

Items are configured by Vendor as all stands for a particular Vendor offer the same items at the same prices

Stands may run out of a particular item, so the UnavailableItems table has a record for each item that has become unavailable at a given stand (using a composite primary key of ItemId and StandId)

### Problem:

I can create everything just fine until I add the last Foreign Key listed (FK_UnavailableItem_StandId_Stand_Id) with a Delete Rule: Cascaded

SQL Compact 3.5 (using VS 2010 Server Explorer) reports the following error:
***The referential relationship will result in a cyclical reference that is not allowed.***

I understand that if I have an record in the UnavailableItem table, and its Vendor gets deleted, it will try to be deleted twice:

Once because its referenced item was deleted.

Once because its referenced stand was deleted.

However, this does not appear to be cyclical to me. The cascading-deletes branch into two paths (Deleted Stands and Deleted Items) that both end in a the same record being deleted... but it ends there. There is no infinite loop of cascading-deletes after that. Am I missing something, or is this a limitation of the tools I am using?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cascade delete through two branches, it is a limitation of the tool. But cascade delete is generally a bad thing to do to your poor innocent database anyway. Delete from the bottom table and move up. That way if you have 100000000000 records at the bottom you can do them in batches for performance. Cascade delete can cause performance problems.

Comment: I guess there won't be 100 Grecords in SSCE. By not defining the constraints in the database, you force the application to know where to cascade. As the database evolves, it might be prone to errors (leaving inconsistencies in the database) as more references are added.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SSCE does not allow cascade delete along two paths, you could remove the cascade delete for UnavailableItem.StandId.

At least, it will still cascade when a Vendor, or an Item is deleted.

And if UnavailableItem still contains rows for deleted Stands, at least they could be filtered out when joining UnavailableItem with Stand, when building refilling orders...

Comment: I accepted HLGEM's answer as it did answer my question (that it's a limitation of the tool), but +1 and thank you for providing suggested workaround of the limitation!